# How do you make urls like movies.netflix.com

Tags: url, iis, subdomain

There is a www.netflix.com. However once you log in, you browse movies in movies.netflix.com.

I know netflix is built on Apache. But how would a I have a url like that in IIS? What would I do to have www.mysite.com, then have support.mysite.com as a part of that site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called a subdomain. IIS's control panel should have a page on there for it. Just create one and choose the directory to place it. If you put an index.php in that directory, when someone visits support.mysite.com, it will show index.php

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to get from "www.mysite.com" to "support.mysite.com".  Perhaps the OP could clarify?

Answer (score 1):

This is a DNS record that needs to be set up.  Then, just configure your server to handle it like you would any other hostname.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways, but the easiest is either with a web page redirection (when you land on a page it redirects you automatically to another web page), or by having you click a link which takes you to a different host name.

In the example you gave in your question, one way might be having your "Support" navigation menu option (button, pull-down menu, whatever) link to "support.mysite.com".